# java program client side to trigger a server side java program

Tags: java, client-server, client-side, server-side

i'm planning on creating a system that has 2 parts, the first part will be found in the client side while the other part is in the server side. there are 2 different programs here running, the client side will save a data in the database and raise a flag or a trigger which will then be the cause for the server side part to start and retrieve data from the database and process it in an API.

at first i decided on using a scheduler on the server side to continuously run the program and check for any changes in the database using a "status" field, but then this is not that efficient as it would be wasteful to always check for changes.

thus i was hoping you can help me out in finding a different solution to my problem here so that i may do this more efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use database triggers, upon a change in your db you can call a server side method embedded in a jar file.

The following link might help.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39522/execution-of-a-java-program-by-a-trigger

Update :

You can use asynchronous messaging services like jms which would work on publish & publish service, you would need a broker server for this is this way more efficient & elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

For start you can follow to the guide from spring: "*React.js and Spring Data REST*"
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

Here *Spring Data Rest* on Back-end side with events(4th part of guide, right what you need 'from the box') and *ReactJs* as Front-end client.

If you are new in ReactJs it won't be a problem, you can follow guide from scratch.